# HTML table with a freeze header

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have created a table with a freeze header but the problem is there is a long empty space appearing at the end of the page, I don't what is the problem, here is the link

http://www.nimaxseals.com/product_details.php?id=27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

Wrap the content outside footer with a div like

```
<footer></footer>
<div class="extdivcont">
<div><table class='data-table'></table></div>
<div><table class='data-table'></table></div>
<div><table class='data-table'></table></div>
</div>

.extdivcont .data-table
{
display: none;
}
```

Comment: @Mohamed Badr i checked you have not added any wrapper div for data-table contents after footer.can you add as in the code and check it..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 880px; left: 195px; visibility: hidden;">
    <table id="maintable" class="data-table"></table>
</div>
```

There's a hidden table who's height 17286px and that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @MohamedBadr : It's not just about saying 'that's not working' . You need to say more if you want help!

Comment: I applied what you said and it didn't work, I am still confused why is that empty space !

Comment: @MohamedBadr : try with `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define height of parent div for table#maintable and make it's overflow: hidden;